# mongodb - Delete many users from multiple collections

Tags: mongodb

How to perform delete from multiple collections. Currently, my query looks like below and works for deleting one user at a time from 3 different collections and also cloudinary. I am planning to pass an array of userId instead of just one userId to the api.

userIdArray will be `[userId1, userId2, userId3....]`

Do I need a `for` loop or can this be done using an efficient mongodb query? Also for Cloudinary can I pass multiple tags?

```
handler.delete(async (req, res) => {
  const {userId, profileCompletion} = req.body;
  const db = await getMongoDb();
  await db.collection('likes').deleteMany( 
    {
      users: { $in: [userId] },
    }
  )
  await db.collection('messages').deleteMany( 
    {
    $or: [ {"from": userId}, {"to": userId}]
    }
  )
  await db.collection('users').deleteOne( 
    {
      "_id": userId,
    }
  )
  if(profileCompletion) {
    await cloudinary.api
    .delete_resources_by_tag(userId)
    .then(result=>console.log(result));
    await cloudinary.api
    .delete_folder(`users/${userId}`)
    .then(result=>console.log(result));
    
  }
  
  res.json({"Deleted": "success"});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `$in` keyword, just like you used in the `likes` collection above.

If you are running mongodb on a cluster or a replica set I would also recommend wrapping your delete operations inside a `transaction`. This will ensure all delete operations succeed together or fail together, preventing part of the data being deleted in some scenarios where one or more of your operations fail to execute.

Your code will look like this:

```js
const client = await getMongoClient(); // You will need to somehow get the mongo client.
const db = await getMongoDb();
const session = client.startSession();
try {
  await db.collection('likes').deleteMany( 
    {
      users: { $in: usersIds },
    },
    {session}
  );

  await db.collection('messages').deleteMany( 
    {
    $or: [ {"from": { $in: usersIds }}, {"to": { $in: usersIds }}]
    },
    {session}
  );

  await db.collection('users').deleteOne( 
    {
      "_id": { $in: usersIds },
    },
    {session}
  );
  
  await session.commitTransaction();
} catch (error) {
  await session.abortTransaction();
} finally {
  await session.endSession();
}
```

More on transactions:

- [Mastering MongoDB — Introducing multi-document transactions in v4.0](https://medium.com/hackernoon/mongodb-transactions-5654cdb8fd24)
- [Official NodeJs Driver Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/transactions/)

Comment: Other than wrapping in a session, Your code looks exactly like my question. You have used userId as well which only has one user. For example what would the messages collection query look like? Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, my bad. I updated my code to support multiple users.